# How to change the format of ReadList

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have a quick question, please help me if you have an idea:
1- i need to read the data in another format, in the desired answer the records must be separated by &&, and without braces { } .  in my file each record is written in one line . I have this now:

```
R2 = ReadList["C:\\Users\\hessam\\Documents\\Mathout.txt", String]
result ----> {xP == x + y, yP == x + y + z, zP == z, wP == w} // i dont want this
// must be this xP == x + y && yP == x + y + z && zP == z && wP == w
```

String replace does not help because each returned record is a separate string. i dont know how to handle it.

```
StringReplace[R2, "," -> "&&"]
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume R2 contains a list of strings as returned from ReadList.

We may then use the 2 argument form of StringRiffle to obtain what you want:

```
res=StringRiffle[R2, "&&"]
```

[image]

Head reveals that this is really only one string:

```
Head[res]
(*String*)
```